# UWP: Carousel Control issues with Observable collection used to update images

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am using the Carousel Control from the UWP sample app toolkit which gets its images from an observable collection.

MainPage.xaml

```
  <Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d">

   <Grid>
     <Border Margin="0">
  <controls:Carousel x:Name="CarouselControl"
              InvertPositive="True"
              ItemDepth="300"
              ItemMargin="0"
              ItemRotationX="0"
              ItemRotationY="45"
              ItemRotationZ ="0"
              Orientation="Horizontal"
              ItemSource ={x:bind ViewModel.CollectionOfImages}
              SelectedIndex="4">
    <controls:Carousel.EasingFunction>
      <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
    </controls:Carousel.EasingFunction>
    <controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Image Width="200"
              Height="200"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
              Source="{x:Bind ImagePath}"
              Stretch="Uniform" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
  </controls:Carousel>
</Border>
```

MainPageViewModel.cs

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ImageClass> CollectionOfImages {get; set;}
    
    //event called by other pages in my app with a collection of images
    // these images are used to populate the observable collection which is bound to the ImageSource 
    // in the xaml
    private void RepopuateCollection(ObservableCollection<string> randomImages)
    {
        this.CollectionOfImages.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < randomImages.Count; i++)
        {
            ImageClass object = new ImageClass
            {
                ImagePath = randomImages[i],
            };
            this.CollectionOfImages.Add(object);
        }
    }
 }
```

ImageClass.cs

```
 public class ImageClass
 {
     public string ImagePath;
  }
```

When i load the stage from say Page 1 i can see these images displaying correctly but when i navigate to say Page 2 which also uses the same carousel but with different images, i dont see these images be populated. I can see screen with no images. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Could you please share us with a minimal sample by using OneDrive or GitHub? It could be better if you could show us the steps to reproduce the issue of the sample for test.

Comment: Will work on this

Comment: I want to know what your strings `randomImages` look like. Did you import images into the **Assets** of your project, and then get the image path string like this: `"ms-appx:///Assets/image.png"` ?

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT Yes

Comment: Have your issue been resolved? If the issue was not resolved, it is better if you could share us with a [mcve] by using OneDrive or GitHub for us to reproduce the issue and  locate the issue.

Comment: I worked on creating a small reproducer which is is not exactly similar to the above code as it doesn't use MVVM and i couldnt see the issue . I had issues with using ItemSource = {x:bind CollectionOfImages,mode=OneWay}. Turns out that the images would not update on navigating to another page, i tried binding the ItemSource in the code behind and that helped solve the images not being updated. However, I still see that the images don't render but if I resize the app window i can see them, any idea why this might be happening ?

Comment: Thank you for your patience. It is still unclear what is the root issue. A sample can be useful for us to view the reason of the appearance of the issue.

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT I managed to have a workaround for this issue. I did a force update on the app when the list changes during the page navigation. This helped fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are you trying to bind the `Source` property of an `Image` element to an `ObservableCollection<ImageClass>` which is wrong.

You should bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `Carousel` control to the `ObservableCollection<ImageClass>` and then bind the `Source` property to the `ImagePath`. Something like this:

```
<controls:Carousel x:Name="CarouselControl"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.CollectionOfImages}"
                  ...>
    <controls:Carousel.EasingFunction>
        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
    </controls:Carousel.EasingFunction>
    <controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ImageClass">
            <Image Width="200"
                  Height="200"
                  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                  Source="{x:Bind ImagePath}"
                  Stretch="Uniform" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
</controls:Carousel>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. My original implementation has the Image source bound to CollectionOfImages and Source is bound to ImagePath. I messed up while putting up the post. Apologies. However, even with this implementation in place, i face the same issue.